# How to use enable_if correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, enable-if

I need to learn how to use enable_if. For this I need to reimplement the distance function using enable_if. I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class In>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_random_acces_iterator<In>::value, std::iterator_traits<In>::difference_type>::type  my_distance(In begin, In end, std::input_iterator_tag dummy){
  typename std::iterator_traits<In>::difference_type n = 0;
  while(begin!=end){
    ++begin; ++n;
  }
  std::cout << "STEPPING" << std::endl;
  return n;
}

template<class Ran>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_random_acces_iterator<Ran>::value, std::iterator_traits<In>::difference_type>::type my_distance(Ran begin, Ran end, std::random_access_iterator_tag dummy){
  std::cout << "RANDOM" << std::endl;
  return end - begin;
}

template <class I> inline
typename std::iterator_traits<I>::difference_type my_distance_wrapper(I begin, I end){
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category cat;
  return my_distance(begin, end, cat());
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> ve;
  std::list<int> li;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    ve.push_back(i);
    li.push_back(i);
  }
  std::cout << my_distance_wrapper(ve.begin(), ve.end()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_distance_wrapper(li.begin(), li.end()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I thought I could do this by using some function like `std::is_random_acces_iterator<In>::value` similar to `std::is_pod<In>::value`
I checked the [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) but could not find anything for checking if something is a specific iterator.
How would I check if something is an random_acces_iterator? I know I could just do this in a function:

```
template<class T>
bool f(){
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category cat;
  return std::random_access_iterator_tag == cat();
}
```

So my question is basically how do I do function f in a template? And no not using enable_if is not possible, it is a requirement of my task. And am I correct to believe that SFINAE would correctly discard the other function, if I could get function f into that template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the type traits `std::is_same<>` as follows

```
template<typename iterator>
using is_random_access_iterator = 
  std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::iterator_category,
               std::random_access_iterator_tag>;
```

and then

```
template<typename iterator>
std::enable_if_t<is_random_access_iterator<iterator>::value,
                 typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type>
my_distance(iterator a, iterator b) { return a-b; }

template<typename iterator>
std::enable_if_t<!is_random_access_iterator<iterator>::value,
                 typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::difference_type>
my_distance(iterator a, iterator b) { /* ... */ }
```

Here, `std::enable_if_t<,>` is a helper alias defined (since C++14) as

```
template<bool condition, typename type = void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<condition,type>::type;
```

---

Actually, you can also declare your function `f()` as `constexpr` and use it directly within the `enable_if`, i.e. `std::enable_if<f<It>(), ...>`.

Comment: Trying to use your solution gives me the error: '  expected a type, got ‘std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category’'

Comment: @Hakaishin okay, I didn't test it. I forgot a `typename`.

Comment: Don't know why but I can't edit my previous comment. But anyways this whole metaprogramming thing seems to simply do programming but inside of these <>. I see the potential benefit, but sometimes I ask myself if it is worth learning all these things and how often they are actually used...

Comment: @Hakaishin You can only edit a comment within 5 minutes. The meta-programming thing is useful if you do a lot of template stuff, i.e. generic programming. But this is really an entirely different question.

Comment: to impress the ladies with high performant code that is strongly typed and expressive ;)

Comment: Oh I forgot ah typename inside the enable if, that's why it wasn't working for me. Feels so weird to write typename inside of <>, I'm used to have it only at the beginning of lines.